# Scripts for PartialView MVC3 Not Loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP MVC3 for which i am using a partial view but the issue is am not able to load the scripts into the same.
Below is an code for which i have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#bodytag').load(function () {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
</script>
<div class="acc-expand-bkg" id="bodytag">
    <div class="submenu_dropdown clearfix">
        <div class="filter_bar clearfix">
            <div class="left" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <label style="width: auto; margin-top: 7px;">
                    Standard:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("teamDetailId", ViewBag.TeamNames as SelectList, null, new { id = "teamDetailId" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above partial view is not getting loaded with the script. I tried with document.ready neither it worked for it.
Can you please tell me the work around for the same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it work if you put the script block below the parent div?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Load was performed.');
</script>
```

But normally scripts should not be placed inside partial views. They should not be mixed with markup. Normally scripts belong to separate javascript files. So a better approach would be to define a javascript function in a separate file:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('Load was performed.');
}
```

and then invoke this javascript function once you load the partial view using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some url',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#someId').html(result);
        // the partial view was injected into the DOM => now we could
        // invoke our function:
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is used to load content from server using ajax and update the inner content of the specified html element. You have to pass the server `url` as the first argument to the method.

```
$('#bodytag').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

You have to put the script block below the html.